# Got some error when I want to install my own package globally

Tags: pip

I want to install a package from my own project globally, and the structure is as shown in the pic.
But when I used `pip install <package name>`. I got an error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `<package name>` (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for `<package name>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vkrO.png)
Thanks!

I have tried to use pip install --user , but is did not work

Comment: Show us the exact command you typed.  `pip install` by itself is not a valid command.

Comment: But when I used 'pip install <package name>'. I got error

Comment: The stackoverflow ignores <package name>. It is weird.

Comment: Did you register your package on pypi.org ?

Comment: The global here means the package is available for system-wide use and can be imported in any script or interpreter.